# SVN Put request failed at 1059.44MB

Tags: linux, apache, svn

`Error: Commit failed (details follow):   Error: While preparing 'C:\IT-TEST\FILE.iso' for commit   Error: PUT request on '/test-repo/!svn/txr/6581-57h/IT-TEST/FILE.iso' failed`  
I got this error when trying to upload(with SVNTORTOISE) to my repo file which size is more than 1059~1060MB.
What in server side need to be edit?
OS:Oracle Linux
Software: SVN+HTTPd

Comment: Is there free disk space on the server? You need to check the logs.

Comment: Yeap, i check free space, i have around ~ 2TB of free space.

Comment: Grep your `/etc/<where apache config lives/` for `LimitRequestBody` ...

Comment: already do it :( , no matches

Comment: Just be aware you won't recover that space, even if you replace or remove the file. Storing ISO images in your Subversion repository poses a bit of a risk.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding LimitRequestBody 0 to httpd.conf and reloading the service.
Thanks all for help :)

Comment: If this issue occured recently it is due to: `In Apache HTTP Server 2.4.53 and earlier, the default value was 0 (unlimited)` (cf. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)